# Missing entry field in django admin's site after import Tinymce

Tags: python, django, tinymce

After import the Tinymce, the entry of the models.post in the admin's site not show up(red draw). When i restart the page, it's show in a momment then off completely

[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQRn8.png)

**main.admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Author, Category, Post

admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Post)
```

**main.models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse


User = get_user_model()

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.user.username

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    detail = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField(default='')
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
            })
```

Comment: I stuck in this problem for 3hr already :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the installation of `TinyMCE` through `pip install django-tinymce`. Try installing as:

`pip install django-tinymce4-lite`

then,

`from tinymce import HTMLField` (instead of '`tinymce.models import HTMLField`')

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    content = HTMLField('Content')
```